# How to retrieve a file from a remote machine in python using WMI

Tags: python-3.x, wmi

How can I copy over files from a remote PC to my local machine?

I have managed to connect remotely to a Windows PC from another Windows 10 PC using python WMI however there is not much documentation about wmi in python. I'm using Python 3.7.1

```
connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password) # connects to the remote PC
```

Comment: Why don't you copy the file via a regular network connection?

Comment: I can;t install anything on the machine I want to copy from. All I have is the ip address, user name and password for logging on to windows.

Comment: When you open the Windows Explorer and use the path `\\ip.address.of.machine\c$`, what do you see?

Comment: @Tomalak "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

Comment: In Explorer? Hardly.

Comment: @Tomalak Oh, sorry I tried in a different browser. It pop me a prop for entering user name and password. I used the ones I have and I have access to explore the machine folders and run files.

Comment: So that means you can use those network paths to copy files. If you *must* use Python, you can use the [`shutil` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html), but actually just a command line (cmd.exe) `copy \\ip.address.of.machine\c$\path\to\the\file c:\path\on\current\machine` will be enough.

Comment: When in doubt (especially if you don't want to enter username and password every time), map the network drive to one of your drive letters.

Comment: @Tomalak OK. So how do I "log on"? whith WMI or with a diffrerent module? Shutil documentation doesn't mention anything about logging on...

Comment: The easiest way: Map a network drive in Windows explorer and use "save credentials". After that you can use the new drive letter in your paths. All necessary authentication is done automatically.

Comment: @Tomalak Then that misses the point of what I’m trying to write. What I’m writing has all the log-in details and the “copy_from_here” folder read from a txt file. The user has no input.

Comment: Well, that's even better. All I'm saying is: Don't use WMI for this, that's clunky, unnecessarily complicated and very likely a pain to use from Python on top of all that. Use shell scripting instead, either using a plain old batch file (with `net use` and `copy`) or a PowerShell script (with `Copy-Item` and `Get-Credential`). When the login details are in a text file anyway, there doesn't have to be any user interaction. You could probably do it in Python as well, but I'm for keeping it simple.